# Polly -how do I log final error and continue?

Tags: c#, serilog, polly, retry-logic, app-startup

I'm trying to set up Polly in .Net Core 3.1 (Azure Functions v3).

I want to create a Policy in the Startup class which I can inject into functions.

The behaviour that I'm looking for is: 
It should wait And retry 3 times - if the final try fails - it should catch and log the exception (Serilog) otherwise just continue.

At the moment I have the following piece of code:

```
AsyncRetryPolicy emailRetryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt =>
     TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(retryAttempt * 500));
```

As you see I miss the part where it logs the error after 3 tries - and just continue. Any Idea how to do that?

Serilog is also added in Startup class (Partial code shown)

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(al => al.AddSerilog(logger));
```

I'm going to send an email with *MailKit* and want to log if it for some reasons fails. It should not stop the program for running.

Answer (score 5):

The retry policy works in the following way:

- It tries to execute the action

  - If it fails and the policy handles it then it will wait a predefined amount of time before it makes the next try
  - It if fails and the policy does not handle it then it will return with the original value (which can be an exception)
- After the max retries has been reached (1st initial attempt + n retry attempts) and it still fails then it will return with the original value

---

Depending on your business logic, which you would like to wrap with this retry policy, you have the following two options:

1. If it is a function, then you can use a [Fallback policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Fallback). (Obviously if you can provide a fallback value.) In your Fallback you do the logging and then return with the fallback value. You can chain these two policies with the `Policy.WrapAsync`, but be aware of their order.

Sample fallback policy:

```cs
var fallbackPolicy = Policy<YourResponse>
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .FallbackAsync( (ct) =>
    {
         logger.LogError("Operation has been failed after several retries ...");
         return Task.FromResult(new YourResponse { ... });
    });
                
var combinedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(fallbackPolicy, retryPolicy);
```

2. If it a method then you can use the `onRetryAsync` callback of the `AsyncRetryPolicy`

Sample retry policy:

```cs
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        settings.RetryCount,
        _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(settings.SleepDurationInMilliseconds),
        onRetryAsync: (ex, count, context) =>
            logger.LogError("Operation has been failed after several retries ...");
    );
```

---

I would like to emphasize that retry policy is designed for idempotent operations. Any service call, which might send an e-mail as a side-effect is **not an idempotent operation**.

Answer (score 3):

Also had that issue and it took me some time to figure this out, so sharing my solution here.
It's important to note that **the order of policies wrapped matters**

My case:

```cs
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<EmptyResponseException>()
    .Or<Exception>()
    .Or<HttpOperationException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        retryCount: 3,
        sleepDurationProvider: _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
        onRetryAsync: (e, i) => LogHandler.WarningAsync("Retrying due to " + e.Message + " Try " + i + " next."));
var fallbackPolicy = Policy.Handle<EmptyResponseException>()
    .Or<Exception>()
    .Or<HttpOperationException>()
    .FallbackAsync
    (
        async ct =>
            {
                await Task.FromResult(true);
                await LogHandler.CriticalAsync("i'm a fallback action");
                /* do something else async if desired */
            },
        async ex =>
        {
            await LogHandler.CriticalAsync("i'm an actual fallback");
            //throw ex; <<< if you throw here, the fallback action won't happen
        }

    );

_policy = Policy.WrapAsync(fallbackPolicy, retryPolicy);
```

Result:

[image: logs]

It doesn't quite matter what the `fallbackPolicy` or `retryPolicy` are in my case, but if I were to use this instead:

```cs
_policy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, fallbackPolicy);
```

We'd get the fallback execute first, and the retry wouldn't work:

[image]